# Problem: keep prompting user to enter code until the right they input the right values

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm having an error with the following code. It's relatively simple but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Here's a part of the code:

```
    int target=0,nextRow;
    char nextCol;

    while(target == 0)
    {
            printf("Enter a valid target: ");
            scanf("%c%d",&nextCol,&nextRow);
            if(nextCol>= 'a' && nextCol <= 'z') /* convert to uppercase */
                    nextCol=nextCol-32;
            if(nextRow>row || nextRow<1 || nextCol<'A' || (nextCol-64)>col)
                    target=0;
            else
                    target=1;
    }
```

Essentially the user is prompted to input a char and int e.g. B4, C8 etc. Col and Row are predefined integers. If the user-input values are out of bounds target remains as 0. Else target=1 so the loop will exit. When I run this and keep inputing invalid values, "Enter a valid target" starts repeating. Why?

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuiT6.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Comment: Try: `scanf(" %c%d",&nextCol,&nextRow);` Note extra space before `%c`. See duplicate candidate for explanation.

Comment: I don´t think that´s the problem, @kaylum. Read the question twice.

Comment: Do you mean "*When I run this and keep inputing **valid** values*" instead of "*When I run this and keep inputing **invalid** values*"?

Comment: How is `row` and `col` defined?

Comment: @kaylum I guess, OP´s intention is to break out of the loop if the user inputs valid values, but it doesn´t seem to work as expected. The second `if` statement seems to be the cause.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio no, I meant when I keep inputting invalid values. This code is supposed to prevent users from inputting the wrong values. I put in invalid values to see if it will let me..
Also, row=4 and col=5 here

Comment: @kaylum nah, this doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the condition `(nextCol-64)>col` seems to be misplaced.

If you input f.e. `'b'` as input for `nextCol`, the expression would be evaluated to `2 > col` which seems to be wrong.

Also I consider that `col` and maybe even `row` have the value of `0` in which case, the corresponding conditions would always evaluate to `true` and the loop will never terminate as it seems to do.

Overthink the logic of your program!